# Parse html element in element's title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text area element

```
<textarea ng-model="text"></textarea>
```

I have another element icon which on hover displays the text from textarea element

```
<i class="k-icon k-i-paste-plain-text" title="{{text}}">
```

Everything works fine; until a user typed the html in text box eg: 
If the text is "`<b>some random text </b>`" then, in title also it shows

```
<b>some random text </b>
```

I want to know how it can be parsed and appended only the text in the title.

Comment: Don't tag questions as both Angular and AngularJs, they are different frameworks.

Comment: remove the direct binding, and call onchange method, on textarea  and use below code   **** jQuery('<p>' + text+ '</p>').text();**** it will return only text then assing to variable use in title

Comment: @Shikha, I think you are creating duplicate questions for one issue -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899681/adding-filter-wth

Comment: I think solution provided by @AdrianBrand works fine from initial question , but later you mentioned $(text) which is confusing, please few sample inputs and expectedd outputs for title to debug easily

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically encodes html in text before it displays it. This is because you really have to trust the source that the text is coming from as allowing script tags to be injected into the page allows total control over your whole site including access to authentication tokens. Be very very careful with what you are trying to do here.

You can create a filter that allow the html to be displayed

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

And use it with

```
<i class="k-icon k-i-paste-plain-text" title="{{text | unsafe}}">
```

```js
let app = angular.module('app', [])
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <textarea ng-model="text"></textarea>
  <div ng-bind-html="text | unsafe"></div>
</div>
```

Seems you need to bind with the ng-bind-html, not sure if you will get it to work with the title attribute.

Comment: Hi, I have my title appended like this:

<i class="k-icon k-i-paste-plain-text" title="${text}">, So, in this case how to append filter?

Comment: app is the module you created with angular.module('app', []);

Comment: ya, i know that, my concern is for adding | filter with ${}